# ReactJS access assets in public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, when I try to access any asset in the "public" folder (e.g. logo.png) via the browser

```
http://localhost:3000/logo.png
```

I am redirected to the index.html and am not able to see the asset directly (even for any js asset)

Is there any specific configuration needed to enable that ? Also does that change depending on whether the app is ejected or not ?

---------Updated
Below is my package.json script

```
"start": "webpack serve --progress --config config/webpack.dev.js",
"build": "react-scripts build",
```

config/webpack.dev.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const common = require('./webpack.common');
const srcDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  entry: {
    main: ['react-hot-loader/patch', path.join(srcDirectory, 'index.js')]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
     
    }
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },

  mode: 'development',

  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|.ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'resolve-url-loader',
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: 'src',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    },
    stats: 'minimal',
    overlay: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      },
      '/actuator/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },

  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
});
```

Also below is config/webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const srcDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');
const srcDirectory1 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/public');
const distDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['whatwg-fetch',  'raf/polyfill']
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: [srcDirectory, 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', '.html', '.scss', '.css']
  },

  output: {
    path: distDirectory,
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|.ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
         test: /\.txt$/, 
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: 'raw-loader' 
      },
     
      
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: path.join(srcDirectory, 'images'), to: 'images' }
      ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.join(srcDirectory, 'index.html') })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Hi, can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code with issue? It is very difficult to help debug code if we can't see it.

Comment: All I am trying to do here is load assets under public folder in the browser (direct URLs)...Instead of seeing the asset, I am seeing/redirected to index.html

Comment: So then please show us what your code is doing. You've enough rep to understand how SO works.

Comment: please share the screenshot of the your project structure and also if you using webpack and package.json

Comment: Yes, I started with CRA and for now, I build using react and serve via webpack config

Comment: I have updated the relevant code from package.json and my webpack config

Comment: Strangely, despite what my webpack config says, I do not see any "dist" folder and instead my output is under "build" folder

Comment: [This](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) might help. It explains how you can configure your app server to not redirect to index.html file.